# Micro sd card partition strategy for Android (context of wear leveling & data corruption)?

Tags: data-recovery, 7.0-nougat, partitions, mount, app2sd

The primary issue relates to `bad blocks / clusters` and it happens to be android platform.

This is a [Sandisk 128gb  (leave this link - it is not an ad)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010Q57S62). Some cards indicates other problems like memory channels, write speed etc. This card I am using on an `Android Nougat` device.

This is the 2nd time, that the card had corruption issues. The first one I bought got write locked. I've bought a replacement. This card has a lot of bad clusters. 2 things got me to sniff this:

- whatsApp directory (which had a bind to whatsapp dir on internal): the image directory can no longer be written to.
- The phone randomly reboots, and next time the `exFat` partition is not mounted any more (I used `app2sd`, and partitioned the card to `ext4` 10gb to link my apps. The rest if `exfat`).

I ran a `chkdksk` on windows 7, and it would autoterminate on initial run & persisting on running gave me repeated message "# `cluster` moved for file " ( cant recollect exact verbiage ). It could Never complete it but aborted with the message . "corruption found in card "

**Question**
Given this situation, is there any OS utility or 3rd party tool out there, that can complete the card run and mark the bad blocks so, that these bad blocks remain unavailable to write? Yes, I ran `chkdsk` with /r /x options, and that is when it puked with all these errors, and it didn't run untill end. I tried `aparted` for Android which runs `fsck (exFat` sub), and the report came normal in < 1 min which tell me it didnt invoke `bad blocks` routine.

From what I read due to [`'wear leveling'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) the [dynamics](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1048302-start-0.html) changes so `bad sectors` can't be marked permanently, and the only temporary solution would be to do a low level format. Question is - is that so , pl. confirm my understanding?

**Question**
If the above is correct, I wanted to think of ways I can reduce data corruption and have a handle on the above. What I am thinking is , after erasing the data - instead of `exFat`. I will create several `Ext4` partitions.

- An `ext4` for app2sd hidden partition (as is the case presently)
- another `ext4`  pat # 2 for mostly RO data
- `ext4`  pat # 3 for mostly Moderate RW data (like camera photos)
- `ext4`  pat # 4 for mostly high RW  ( like `whatApp` media)

Is this going to help make life better than before?
**Question**
How do I auto `mount` `ext4` (default external storage for Android is `exFat` or `Fat32`)  and that too more than 1 `partition` ? 
**Question**
What files equivalent to `fstab` files in `android` (this is `nougat`) do I add my `custom mount` command to?
**Question**
Any other solution that comes to mind?